# How to shape a nested struct into another without nested loops?

Tags: go

How can I inject A and B's selected values into children C below?

**decoder.go** *([Playground link](https://play.golang.org/p/i12PAMllkD))*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Input struct {
    A []A
}

type A struct {
    AID int
    B []B
}

type B struct {
    BID int
    C []C
}

type C struct {
    // I want to inject only AID and BID here
    // But, without injecting A and B directly
    //   (without recursively)
    CID int
}

func main() {
    res := Input{
        A: []A {
            A {
                AID: 1,
                B: []B {
                    B{ BID: 11, C: []C{{ 111 }, { 111 }}},
                    B{ BID: 12, C: []C{{ 121 }, { 122 }}},
                },
            },
            A {
                AID: 2,
                B: []B {
                    B{ BID: 21, C: []C{{ 211 }, { 211 }}},
                    B{ BID: 22, C: []C{{ 221 }, { 222 }}},
                },
            },
        },
    }

    // I want to inject AID and BID into C
    // WITHOUT nested loops like this:
    for _, a := range res.A {
        for _, b := range a.B {
            for _, c := range b.C {
                fmt.Println(a.AID, b.BID, c.CID)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @EricPauley I see, thx. I wondered whether I'm doing correctly.

Comment: People who keep clicking close link are not following StackOverflow guidelines. _Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once._ This is a specific problem with enough detail, so why did you click on close?

Comment: Please edit the question with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. It's not clear what you want to do. For example, what do you mean by this: "I want to inject AID and BID into C" where `type C struct { CID int }` C has no `AID` or `BID`. What do you meann by inject?

Comment: @peterSO Please read my comment above. Or please give suggestions about how to improve it.

Comment: Obviously, I read your comment above. Clearly, it didn't help.

Comment: Can you be specific please? What didn't understand about the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use nested loop, one solution is using recursive call and reflection to inject the attributes/properties into a struct. In the following implementation, attributes/properties to be injected is wrapped in a struct implement `Injectable` interface. Working example can be found at [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/b7_ZSqmrE4).

1. Define the interface.

   ```
   type Injectable interface {
       InjectTo(v interface{})
   }
   ```
2. Define data structure that holds properties/attributes to be injected, e.g.

   ```
   type Property struct {
       AID int
       BID int
   }

   type C struct {
       // The properties will be injected here
       Property
       CID int
   }
   ```
3. Implement `InjectTo` using reflection and recursive call.

   ```
   //Method must be pointer receiver since p will be used 
   //as temporary placeholder for parent properties/attributes.
   func (p *Property) injectRecursive(v reflect.Value, it reflect.Type, pv reflect.Value) {
       switch v.Kind() {
       case reflect.Struct:
           vt := v.Type()
           //Embedded struct is a 'value' type implement Injectable
           if vt.Implements(it) {
               //Inject value to embedded struct
               ot := pv.Type()
               for k := 0; k < pv.NumField(); k++ {
                   name := ot.Field(k).Name
                   f := v.FieldByName(name)
                   if f.CanSet() {
                       f.Set(pv.Field(k))
                   }
               }
           } else {
               for k := 0; k < v.NumField(); k++ {
                   fv := v.Field(k)

                   //Match by field name.
                   //For more robust and generic solution
                   //consider using other approach, e.g. tag
                   f := pv.FieldByName(vt.Field(k).Name)
                   if f.CanSet() {
                       f.Set(fv)
                   } else {
                       p.injectRecursive(fv, it, pv)
                   }
               }
           }
       case reflect.Slice, reflect.Array:
           for k := 0; k < v.Len(); k++ {
               p.injectRecursive(v.Index(k), it, pv)
           }
       case reflect.Ptr:
           if v.IsValid() {
               p.injectRecursive(v.Elem(), it, pv)
           }
       }
   }

   //InjectTo must be Value (not pointer) receiver
   func (p Property) InjectTo(s interface{}) {
       sv := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(s))
       pv := reflect.Indirect(reflect.ValueOf(&p))
       it := reflect.TypeOf((*Injectable)(nil)).Elem()
       p.injectRecursive(sv, it, pv)
   }
   ```
4. You can inject the properties by:

   ```
   res := Input{...}
   prop := Property{}
   prop.InjectTo(&res)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Go generally encourages an explicit approach, and nested for loops are very explicit in terms of what is actually going on here. There's likely no need to try to find a more concise solution and Go likely won't offer it.